# MySQL - Why does a select statement on an indexed column return the index information, and not the column data?

Tags: mysql

I have a table (InnoDB) that stores an activity log. Each row has a user id, an activity id, and location data. The user id and the activity id columns are indexed, though not unique.

When I query `select *` the data returned looks normal -

```
select * from table
```

When I query user id or activity id with another column (even those 2 together), the data looks normal.

```
select user_id, city from table
```

When I query for just the user id or activity id with a where statement, the data looks normal.

```
select user_id from table where city = 'boulder'
```

The issue arises when I query for just the user id or activity id alone, or query just one with a where statement on the same column with a substring query.

```
select user_id from table
```

or

```
select user_id from table where substring(user_id, 1,5) = '12345'
```

The data returned is not the data in the field, but what looks like the index location (or something similar). I dropped the indexes, and the problem was fixed, but reappeared as soon as I added the indexes back.

Example without index -

```
user_id   
-------
123456789
231234567
234567543
```

Example with index -

```
user_id
-------
081357652234
100000000000000
1000000000011
```

I've tried restarting the server, and then reloading the data from the api, but nothing helped. I've tested this on other tables in the same database without experiencing this problem.

Is this a bug or some mistake I made in configuration?

Comment: Are those user_ids (081357652234 and 100000000000000) not in the table? Adding an index may have just changed the order that results are returned in.

Comment: @davidfg4 if those ids were in the table then there would be something even more wrong with the issue as the where clause should only return ids containing 12345.In any case, if the problem occurs only on this table it may be useful to run a `check table 'table'`

Comment: Good clarification - they are not in the table. The user id length is capped at 12 characters.

Comment: The version is 5.5.31

Comment: How did you name your index?

Comment: Oh and referring to my previous comment, it may be useful not to call the table 'table', you never know

Comment: Try putting backticks around user_id

Comment: Another clarification - it looks like if I try the query  -      SELECT user_id from table where substring(user_id, 1,5) = '12345'  it can return both user_ids and index locations.

Comment: what data-type is user_id ??

Comment: @JoeMinichino - good point about 'table' - it's actually called user_activity

Comment: the indexes are u_id for user_id and a_id for activity_id. User_id is varchar, activity_id is int.

Comment: And backticks just returns 'user_id'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would:

- change the name of the table (i see you updated it to user_activity) to avoid possible bugs due to table name being also a keyword in sql
- make a backup of the db
- run a `check table user_activity` for errors
- check that user_id is an int type

**UPDATE**: As i can see from one of your comments that user_id is a varchar, you may have run into some bug because the second and third id returned by your query look like binary.
As you're working with InnoDB you can't run `REPAIR` but you can look at [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/rebuilding-tables.html). It may also be a good idea to dump the db and reload it to see if your problem is circumstantial or consistently happening no matter what.

Comment: Thanks Joe, I'm going to try this.

Comment: I had to wait to dump and reload the db overnight as it is too big. The issue is still there.

Comment: It looks like you were right about varchar creating a bug - I created a copy of the table, dropped the index, changed the user_id datatype to int, and recreated the index. It works now. What's odd is that this seemed to fix the activity_id column (which was already int datatype). Thanks!